# PHP Class in namespace not found

Tags: php

I tried to the Person Class from the Person Namespace, all included in a autoloader file.
When running the program I get the error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Person\Person' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/index.php on line 13
```

Here is my code and structure:
index.php

```
<?php
    include 'includes/autoloader.inc.php'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>testproject</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php            
            $person1 = new Person\Person('Lucas', 'Fußball', 21);

            echo $person1->getPerson();
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

autoload function (should be working fine):

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');

function myAutoLoader($className) {
    $path = "classes/";
    $extension = ".class.php";
    $fullPath = $path . $className . $extension;

    if (!file_exists($fullPath)){
        return false;
    }

    include_once $fullPath;
}
```

The Person class:

```
<?php
namespace Person;

class Person {
    private $name;
    private $hobby;
    private $age;

    public static $drinkingAge = 21;

    public function __construct($name, $hobby, $age) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->hobby = $hobby;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getPerson() {
        return 'Name: ' . $this->name . '<br>Hobby: ' . $this->hobby . '<br>Alter: ' . $this->age;
    }

    public static function setDrinkingAge($newDA) {
        self::$drinkingAge = $newDA;
    }
}
```

My folder structure is as following:

```
index.php
classes
|_ Person
| |_ Person.class.php
includes
|_ autoloader.inc.php
```

Comment: maybe try: composer dump-autoload

Comment: it realy is autoloader.inc.php. When I remove the namespace part, everything is working fine.

Comment: composer dump-autoload is a terminal command or where should I try this. I just started php today :)

Comment: @Falko Try to use `$fullPath = $path . str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . $extension;` and then replace the `classes/_Person/_Person.class.php` path with `classes/Person/Person.class.php`.

Comment: At least print `$path . $className . $extension` to double check the filename path. I believe, your path is not a proper one, so you should build the proper path for your classes.

Comment: @Ihor Vyspiansky nice. This worked. So what you did there is you replaced the '\' written in the index.html with a '/' to prepare a path in the autoloader file?

Comment: @Falko Yeah, this is exactly the idea.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky Well caught. When you run PHP on Windows you can use either separator for paths (forward slash and backslash) but Linux will only understand the former.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not dump whatever `$fullPath` is generated? Also, why not use any of the existing classloaders?